# how to set maximum nuSOAP webservice access frequency in php?

Tags: php, nusoap

Like if any **client tries to access my web service more than 100 times in a minute it should throw an error message or block the client**.

I searched this question and got a link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251521/maximum-server-file-access-frequency][1]

But I could not get the thing properly.
I want to set maximum server acces frequency. If things are not clear please do ask and help me out.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In similar circumstances, I used the following technique:

- Each time a user access the service, log this with a timestamp
- When a user accesses the service, check to see if they have more than X number of log entries in the last X minutes
- If no, allow the request
- If yes, disallow the request (perhaps with a warning why)
- Cron job to clear the table used for logging of all entries more than X minutes old ('cos we don't care about old ones)

If you're not passing some sort of user token with the requests, maybe use the IP.

HTH,

G

Comment: And of course if it's just a crude block when there's too many requests from ANY user, don't log against any sort of user ID, but just log the timestamp.